# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication 403 Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 2 app using Windows Authentication. When I run it within Visual Studio (using the built-in IIS), under the same domain, I was able to login using my credential. But when I deployed it to the server, which is also on the same domain, in-house, I got the "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." error.

I notice that when running it from within Visual Studio, opening the site from IE automatically logs me on, no prompts. But when trying to access it from the server (again, on the same domain), IE prompts me to log-on, and eventually gave the 403 error.

I'm not sure if there are extra settings that I need to do on my app, on the server, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the Application Pool to run under a privileged account?

Comment: My application bool uses the NetworkService account, is that the right one? Or do I have to use something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I've created a new ApplicationPool and somehow it's working now :) Not sure what was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm encountering random 403. I've made apps/pools work dozens of times. I know that IUSRS and etc. all have directory level permissions. I'm tring to do basic authentication but it never even asks me for credentials.

Comment: Maybe it's a munged webconfig? Usually that will at least throw up runtime errors instead of a 403...

Comment: I don't like it when mystery actions fix the problem, but yeah, by disabling and then re-enabling basic authentication (after accessing it with anonymous auth) it worked.